# Storing data permanently to file

Tags: android, storage

```
fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
fos.write(FirstNmstring.getBytes());
fos.close();
```

I used this code to store data in a file in internal memory of mobile. Just as I make another entry into my application, the existing record gets deleted. I want to add every entry that I enter. could any one help me out on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open the file for Append

```
fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_APPEND);
```

Everything you write to it will be appended at the end of the file.